# Random values for a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Low = 10
High = 25
R = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)

Sheets("ITEMS DATA").Range("D4:D39").Value = R
```

I would like for the range stated to return a random number, but it returns the same random number for the whole range (D4:D39).  I would like to return a different random number for the range stated but don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Mike:

Try this:

```
Low = 10
High = 25
For c = 4 To 39
    R = Int((High - Low + 1) * Rnd() + Low)
    Sheets("ITEMS DATA").Cells(c, 4).Value = R
Next
```

Of course, you can change the two arguments in the Cells() method to your liking.

Comment: That was what I meant :blush:

Answer (score 1):

You have created one random value, assigned it to R, and then put that value into your range. There are a few ways you can do what you want to do. I'm assuming there is a good reason not to just paste the formula into the cells directly, so:

```
    Range("B1:B21").Formula = "=Int((A1 - A2)+1) * Rand() + A2"
```

would do it, assuming that A1 and A2 hold High and Low respectively.

Edited to remove wrong answers, and this one has been tested.

Comment: I tried your first example and it does the same thing.  I can't get your second example to work.

Comment: DOh, yes of course, you need to iterate over the range setting each cell, instead of setting the whole range in one go. The second example will have the same problem. I think Range.Formula is the way to go.

Comment: Are you talking about your first example or second?  If so would I change where it says .Range to Range.Formula?  Thanks

Comment: For the record, I have removed the wrong answers that are referred to in the comments above.